# What happens if you loot everything?

Tags: state-of-decay

What happens if you loot everything in State of Decay? Do you just slowly watch everyone die, or is there some sort of regeneration?

Answer (score 5):

Once a location has been fully looted it will be marked with an '**ⓧ**' symbol. Screenshot:

[image].

> - If an outpost is established at a location where some resources remain (the Ammo/ Food/ Fuel/ Material/ Medicine icon depicted on the map once the building is fully searched), that outpost will automatically produce a small amount of that resource per (real-time) day, reducing the daily consumption (known as the Resource Cache bonus). It will continually give you resource benefits as long as the outpost is up.
> - If an empty building is selected as an outpost (or its resource depleted), the outpost icon becomes a Fort icon (similar to Enclave icon, but has the color green)

<sup>- [State of Decay Wiki on Outposts](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Outposts)</sup>
So try not fully looting a location if you want to make it give a Resource Cache bonus. Otherwise, the only way a fully looted location will "regenerate" resources is when you [ask Lily in the Radio Room to 'Make a Radio Call looking for resources' (Survey Support)](http://stateofdecay.wikia.com/wiki/Radio#Survey_Support), and when the result of that call leads to a fully looted location. In that case, that location will regenerate whatever resource you made a radio call for.

Comment: A little update: Firstly, no-resource "forts" no longer produce ammunition. Also, be aware that each outpost costs 1 construction material/day

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that you cannot run out, because you can radio asking for supplies, and the requested supplies will spawn on the map.

Answer (score 0):

- When your base runs out of Food, survivors will fight over the remaining food, lowering morale. Hungry or starving survivors will lose max health and/or stamina. Eventually some will run away (usually with part of your meager remaining supply).
- Materials: Occasionally the event "need to fix the wall" pops up, taking 5-15 materials off your supply. If you don't have enough material then Morale will drop.
- Fuel: No known effect
- Medicine: Obviously sick and injured people can't heal without medicine.
- Ammo (this one's my guess): People will not feel unsafe and eventually leave.

Finally, the Radio Command option does not "Spawn" resources. It only points to the places that you didn't search or didn't loot.

Comment: "*[The Radio Command option] only points to the places that you didn't search or didn't loot.*" I remember being led multiple times to a an already fully looted location when I made a radio call looking for resources. This in the PC version.

Comment: @galacticninja I thought that too - in my case, there really was a stash I'd missed (hidden behind things at a farm). Once I'd located it and looted, Lilly started giving me new locations for things (places I'm _certain_ I've looted dry before)